# Parse / MongoDB / NoSQL: Is it better to have larger (fewer) or smaller (more) objects / records?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, nosql

I am currently designing an app where a user uploads several daily informartion. 
I see two different ways to accomplish this:

1. **Fewer, larger objects:** Save all information in an `array` in the `_User` class of Parse.
2. **More, smaller objects:** Create a new class `Information` and save every information there with a pointer to the `_User` class.

Let's assume the `Information` class contains 1,000,000 records:

Which option is preferable? Are there actually any **CPU / RAM** differences regarding queries? Since in case 1 all the information are stored in the `PFUser.currentUser()`'s object, so there is actually no need for a `query`.

Comment: What do you mean by storing all information in array? Do you want to store some repeating attributes about an object in an array? e.g. purchases a particular made? associated addresses to a user etc?

Comment: Information like daily steps. The array would get larger every day.

Comment: Well, this is MongoDB recommendation. If your array is not too big (causing total document size exceeding 16 MB), then you should store in array inside of main document. However, if this is not case, go for separate collection

Comment: Again, another dimension. If you don't need historical data whenever you retrieve main object, split it to another collection.

Comment: Thanks. What about CPU / RAM usage for case 2? Is it insignificant?

Comment: CPU really doesn't matter as it's more IO bound operation. More RAM is always good as MongoDB will be able to fit most of it's working set there for quick retrieval. If you application read a user profile along with historical data (in your case steps), it suggested to load all at once and do processing in your app and avoid frequent trips to server.

Comment: Do not start a new project with Parse because it is shutting down at the end of January 2017.

Comment: I will be using Parse server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't realistically store more than a few hundred items (depending on the item size, if it's a simple number then the count could be a lot higher) in an array on an object before you'll start seeing issues, and eventually the record will be so big you can't actually save any changes to it. So, using pointers is better.

If you're going to have a huge dataset then it's more important to consider the technology you're using first, and it's ability to scale and index the data. After that you can decide how to structure the data best for that platform.

On parse, use smaller objects with pointers and relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you maybe share the source for your last sentence?

Comment: No explicit reference, various parse forum discussions, tutorials and experience